# Send data from Arduino to Android (AppInventor2) via HC-06 bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, send, app-inventor

I am trying to send the number "25" from arduino to android application created by using MIT AppInventor2. At the same time, I want to make "on" or "off" a LED by clicking "lock" and "unlock" buttons on the android app. There is no problem making LED status "on" and "off" but I can not read the 25 on the application. I only read 2 or 5. I read 25 very very rarely.

What is the problem about my arduino code or AppInventor blocks?

Arduino code:

```
int ledPin = 13;
String readString;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);   
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(25);// Here I want to send 25
delay(20); 

while (Serial.available()) {
delay(3);  
char c = Serial.read();
readString += c; 
}
if (readString.length() >0) {
// Serial.println(readString);
if (readString == "on")     
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
}
if (readString == "off")
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
}
readString="";
} 
}
```

[image]

Edit: Time interval for AppInventor clock is 1000.

Comment: you might want to do a search in the App Inventor forum like this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/bluetooth%7Csort:date